# Scroll on list with arrow keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, arrow-keys

so I have a searcher I'm building, and I struggling with the arrow keys navigation. I can't workaround to scroll through the navigation, I don't know if I'm explaining myself.

[image]

for example, if I have all the results (or more than 7 in this case), and I want to navigate to the last one, the state changes ok (the highlighted bg moves through the focused option good), but the list doesn't scroll, so when one that is not in view is focused, I can't see it and I have to scroll with the trackpad.

My code:

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [filteredPosts, setFilteredPosts] = useState<ContentfulPost[]>(posts)
  const [focusedPost, setFocusedPost] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const filter = search
      ? posts?.filter(
          (p) =>
            p.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
            p.author[0].name
              .toLocaleLowerCase()
              .includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
            p.tag.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
        )
      : posts
    setFilteredPosts(filter)
  }, [search, posts])

  const keyPress = useCallback((event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      setIsOpen(false)
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      setFocusedPost((prev) => (prev <= 0 ? 0 : prev - 1))
    } else if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      setFocusedPost((prev) =>
        prev >= filteredPosts?.length - 1 ? filteredPosts?.length - 1 : prev + 1
      )
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress, false)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress, false)
    }
  }, [keyPress])

<div
            className={clsx('rounded-xl overflow-auto flex flex-col', s.modal)}
          >
            <div className="sticky top-0 pb-2 bg-white">
              <input
                ref={searcherInputRef}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  const value = e.target.value
                  setSearch(value)
                }}
                type="text"
                className="text-gray-800 border-b border-gray-300 border-solid px-6 flex min-w-full pt-5 pb-4 placeholder-gray-500 focus:outline-none"
                placeholder="Buscar..."
              />
            </div>
            <div className="px-3 flex flex-col pb-2">
              {filteredPosts?.map((post, idx) => (
                <Link
                  key={idx}
                  href={`/${getSectionSlug(post.category)}/${post.slug}`}
                >
                  <a
                    onMouseEnter={() => setFocusedPost(idx)}
                    className={clsx(
                      'px-6 py-4 rounded-lg text-gray-800 noDecoration',
                      {
                        'bg-gray-100': focusedPost == idx
                      }
                    )}
                  >
                    {post.title}{' '}
                    <span className="ml-1 text-14 text-gray-600">
                      en {post.category}
                    </span>
                  </a>
                </Link>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this? thanks!

Comment: Use another `useEffect` hook that watches the `focussedPost` state. Whenever that state changes, find the element that belongs to it with a reference and scroll to it.